# Setting prototype of a function as prototype of another function for doing Subclassing (with Object.setPrototypeOf()))

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm not sure if the  Title actually made any sense but however I'm trying to  set a functions prototype to "sub classes" prototype.

For coming example;

What I try to do is : I have a `user` and `paidUser` . `paidUser` is `subclass`  of`user`

User Factory function :

```
    function userCreator(name, score) {
      this.name = name;
      this.score = score;
    }
    userCreator.prototype.sayName = function(){console.log("hi");}
    userCreator.prototype.increment = function(){this.score++;}
```

And I can create a new user with `new` keyword. so far so good.

```
const user1 = new userCreator("Phil", 5);
```

Now , coming to `Subclassing` . (`accountBalance` is just a silly property special for `paidUser` for my example)

```
    function paidUserCreator(paidName, paidScore, accountBalance){
      userCreator.call(this, paidName, paidScore);
      this.accountBalance = accountBalance;
    }
```

now I want to set `prototype` of my `userCreator` as the `prototype` of `paidUserCreator` `Factory Function`

The following line works perfectly, but I don't understand it quite. `Object.create` function is supposed to created an empty object and that empty objects `__proto__` must be the given parameter.

```
paidUserCreator.prototype =Object.create(userCreator.prototype);

paidUserCreator.prototype.increaseBalance = function(){
  this.accountBalance++;
}
```

Another point what I don't understand is :

Why the following line doesn't work ?

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(paidUserCreator, userCreator.prototype);
```

For completion :

```
const paidUser1 = new paidUserCreator("Katarina", 4, 12);
```

PS: Yes I know the `Class` keyword is much cleaner and nicer to read but I want to  learn how to do it in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the last question:

> Why the following line doesn't work ?

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(paidUserCreator, userCreator.prototype);
```

It will, but you need to set the prototype of `paidUserCreator.prototype` not the function `paidUserCreator` so that when an instance looks for something on the `paidUserCreator.prototype` and doesn't find it, it will look to `userCreator.prototype`.

```js
function userCreator(name, score) {
  this.name = name;
}
userCreator.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log("hi");
}

function paidUserCreator(paidName, paidScore, accountBalance) {
  userCreator.call(this, paidName, paidScore);
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(paidUserCreator.prototype, userCreator.prototype);

let p = new paidUserCreator("Mark", 98, 200.5)
p.sayName()
```

`paidUserCreator.prototype = Object.create(userCreator.prototype)` is similar. `Object.create` makes a new object and sets it's prototype to point to the object passed in. When you do this you are replacing `paidUserCreator.prototype` with a new object that is prototype linked to `userCreator.prototype`. One caveat with this is that if there is anything on `paidUserCreator.prototype` that you need it will be lost because you are replacing the whole object, not just setting the prototype.

Here's an example where that might bite you:

```js
function userCreator(name, score) {
    this.name = name;
}
userCreator.prototype.sayName = function(){console.log("hi");}

function paidUserCreator(paidName, paidScore, accountBalance){
    userCreator.call(this, paidName, paidScore);
}

// points to the paidUserCreator function
console.log(paidUserCreator.prototype.constructor)

// replace protoype with new object
paidUserCreator.prototype = Object.create(userCreator.prototype);

// now paidUserCreator.prototype has no constructor property
// so it defers to paidUserCreator
console.log(paidUserCreator.prototype.constructor)
```